# Zip Contents of Directory without cd'ing into directory

Tags: ubuntu, zip, compression, archive

This is probably a duplicate, but I cannot find it. I've needed to know if this is possible for several personal projects as well as a few at work. I need to know if there is a flag or some method on the zip utility for ubuntu/linux system that will allow me to zip the contents (all files and sub directories in a folder) with that folder that I'm targeting being the root of the folder without needing to `cd` into that folder...

For Example
I  have a frontend that I am compiling with NPM. From the root of the project, I run my build command. This outputs the build assets to `dist`. I need the contents of the `dist` directory to be the root of the a zip that I need to compress them into without `dist` showing up in the zip archive, however I would also need to maintain the structure of any subdirectories inside of the `dist` directory.

I want to point out that I'm using a static sites build process for example here, but I'm could apply this to multiple build processes across my org at the moment, however all of our scripts have a `cd` stmt somewhere in their scripts that cd's into the out directory.

To quickly elaborate, I've been working with `Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008)` that is installed on ubuntu and macos. I am not opposed to installing a separate 3rd party util that accomplishes this as long as the util has a small footprint

Thank You.

Comment: Don't think `zip` supports that feature. Man page for `7z` doesn't have anything either.

Comment: Please check this answer in UNIX/Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182036/101265